# Stepping through a program using Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, ide, step-into

How do I step through the program one line at time.

Also, how do I view the console input?

I recently installed Eclipse IDE here:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (includes Incubating components)

[image: Here is a snapshot of the where I am at]

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html I guess debugging should apply to C/C++ too.

Comment: Error while launching command gdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Run, Debug Configurations and click the Debugger tab.

Make sure that there is a gdb debugger selected. If not click Browse find the gdb.exe. It will probably be in your installation directory (of eclipse I mean under the /bin subdir).

Hope it helped. :D

Comment: After I installed Eclipse I looked for the install directory and could not find it...usually they are in Program Files or directly in the C drive for some applications like XAMPP...this would pose my first obstacle...where is my install directory...does Eclipse self-install in the directory containing the eclipse.exe setup file...I know where this is.  But there is no bin directory

Comment: @stack.user.1 I obviously do not know where your install dir is. Just search your system for eclipse.exe and you should be able to find it, or check the path under your desktop shortcut or something.

Comment: I see no bin in the directory that my executable points to.  However I already knew this b.c. I create the shortcut manually from the install directory...I'm just going to re-install...something went wrong...oddly enough all hell broke loose last time I tried to install Eclipse

Comment: There is no uninstall in the control Panel.  I can't even do a re-install

Comment: Eclipsed is not installed, rather just copied somewhere. So there is no uninstall. Is this homework btw?